# How can I dismiss a tab based app upon logout?

Tags: wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I'm currently looking to dismiss a tab based app as a modal (swipe down) upon logout. setStackRoot switches screens but the behavior doesn't seem too user friendly.

Comment: Could you provide more details, e.g. what technology are you using and how, and an example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: I'm on react-native-navigation v2 by wix. I have a tab based app (4 tabs), and I want to switch to a single screen app when the user logs out. I've tried using setStackRoot but couldn't manage to get a "swipe down animation" upon logging out. Hope this helps.